# PHP MySQL array data only works within brackets?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using this array on my website:

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteconfig WHERE setting='main'") 
 or die(mysql_error());  
 while($admin_data = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){

 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 0){
    echo "0";
}
 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 1){
    echo "1";
}
 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 2){
    echo "2";
}
 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 3){
    echo "3";
} 
 }
```

The issue I am having with it is that the "if statements" only work within the {  } brackets of the array? I am trying to get it so that I could add the array into a separate include file and then "include: 'arrayfile.php';" on the page that I wish to use the information on. Then I would be able to use the if statements anywhere. Although, when I take the if statements out of the brackets, no information shows and nothing is being echoed or I am just getting "0" all the time?

Comment: I think you may be a bit confused about scope.  The `while` loop goes over each fetched row, and there can be many of those.

Comment: It seems you are using terms you don't quite understand. Can't you rephrase your question without the word "array"?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the if statements only work between the top { bracket and bottom } bracket, they don't work if I use them somewhere else on the page? How can I use them without having them between the brackets?

Comment: Fine, I'll say it. mysql_ is deprecated, please look in to using prepared statements. http://jp1.php.net/mysqli for MYSQLI and http://jp1.php.net/pdo for PDO

Comment: The reason they don't work, is because you are checking every row in the database that matches that particular sql command. You have to iterate over every row. Calling these conditional statements through a function as @wegus suggested would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

there is a lot of **do nots** in your code, but to start with your question:

try to put your if clauses into a separate function! You'll gonna have only this one function call within the while loop and you could put this function in an includable piece of code as you want!

second hint: Starting with a third **if** you should think of using a switch/case Statement!

third hint: try to use mysql_fetch_object, the resulting $admin_data->close_site might be better to read!

There is much more to say, but i think it would be too much for now

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteconfig WHERE setting='main'")  or die(mysql_error());  
 $admin_data = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 0){
     echo "0";
 }
 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 1){
     echo "1";
 }
 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 2){
    echo "2";
 }
 if($admin_data['close_site'] == 3){
     echo "3";
 }
```

If your getting 0, doesn't that mean the 'close_site' row is 0?

Comment: It should mean that, but in the database it isn't set to 0. It shows the correct value when used between the brackets but not when outside of the brackets?